# Connecting a Scanner object to a System.in object and using Scanner methods

Tags: java

Here is my problem:

I am trying to use Scanner and System.in to take the input from a keyboard and assign it to an int variable.

This is what I have (the full program is included below):

```
// this program will use scanner objects and system inputs
public class Scanner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number;  
             // declares integer "number"

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  // declares referance variable (Scanner class) "keyboard", creates       
  // Scanner object that 
  // reads input from System.in, then assigns address of Scanner object 
  // to the reference variable "keyboard"
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------     
        System.out.println("Enter an integer value: ");
             // displays text 
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
            // assigns keyboard input to "number" as integer value

        System.out.println("You entered the integer " + number);
           // displays "number" to see if the program worked
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the program in the windows command prompt using javac, I get this error message:

```
error: constructor Scanner in class Scanner
cannot be applied to given types;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

required: no arguments
found: InputStream
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

error: cannot find symbol
            number = keyboard.nextInt();
                             ^
symbol:   method nextInt()
location: variable keyboard of type Scanner
2 errors
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a naming clash**. You have to make your `Scanner` class unique from Java language perspective, there are 2 options to do that:

1. **Rename the class**

   - to some other name so that there till be no more naming clash
2. **Make the `Scanner` class unambiguous**

   - by using Fully Qualifed Names

     ```
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         int number;
         java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter an integer value: ");

         number = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.println("You entered the integer " + number);
     }
     ```

Comment: I renamed the class and still received two error messages. Then I tried what yanyu posted below and inserted in the very top line "import java.util.Scanner" and it worked perfectly. I also went back and tried compiling it with the class name as Scanner again, but including the "import java.util.Scanner" at the top, and received error messages again. So I had to both change the class name to something other than Scanner, and include the import command before the main method in order to get it working. Either one alone would not work. Thank you, that was really fast!

Answer (score 0):

You should rename you class Scanner - the error is that, you use class with name Scanner from Java standard library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer value: ");

        number = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered the integer " + number);

    }
}
```